# Check for winner in puzzle game

Tags: javascript

I made a sliding images game of 15 and so far everything works.  However I can't figure out how to determine when the user wins the game by arranging all the images (number 1 through 15) in order.  Right now I'm just trying to figure out how to determine if the user arranged the first 4 numbers in order because if I can get that done rest should be easy.  I will post my code bellow and if anyone has any ideas or suggestions on how to do this that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution for a validation function would be to loop through all the `<img>` elements in your table and evaluate whether the source attribute matched your point in the loop.  Pseudo-coded it could look something like:

```
IMAGES = get all image tags from table
for i = 1 to IMAGES.length {
    if IMAGES[i-1].source != "Buttons\\"+i+".png" return false;
}

return true; // Puzzle solved
```

An actual possible solution would be something like this (using myTable as ID).  This will simply alert out each image it finds.  Replace the alert inside with your checking logic:

```
var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable");
if (myTable) {
    var images = myTable.getElementsByTagName("img");
    if (images && images.length > 0) {
        for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
            alert("Image " + i + ": " + images[i].src);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would IMAGES just be an array with 15 indexes (1 through 15) since each image is represented by a number 0 to 15?

Comment: Yes, you could get such an array.  The trick is to (1) get the table element and then from that (2) get all elements by tag name "img".  This will give you your array.  Obviously you'd have to clean the pseudo-code up, but i'm confident that it is the correct direction to solve your problem.

Comment: I've updated my code (see above) with what you suggested to check if the first 4 numbers are in order, but having no luck.

Comment: Ahh... because my code was not real code.  It was only pseudo-code.  I'll modify what i did to try and provide more clarity.

Comment: I tried to translate it to code with best of my ability, but I'm also new to javascript : )

Comment: Just to clarify document.getElementById(id), id would be the id I assign to the table id in HTML for example like <table id="imageTable"> and myTable.getElementsByTagName("img") would be id for each cell in the table (<td id="imgOne">, <td id="imgTwo">...)?

Comment: Correct on the ID.  getElementsByTagName would return you DOM objects (images, specifically).  No need for IDs there.  Then you can for loop through that array and for each object you can check it's src attribute.

Comment: I've added a little more help into my second example (I've actually run this and it works).

Comment: Alert is working.  Just need to figure out the actual logic now.

Comment: Assuming that the HTML above shows the "solution", then the logic to detect a wrong answer would be something like: `images[i].src != "Buttons\\" + (i+1) + ".png"`.  You'd also ONLY want to loop through `images.length - 1` since the last image is your blank.

Comment: Right now I'm trying to get at least one image working.  For example I want to display a message when 1 is in correct position I use: if (images[0].src == "Buttons/1.png") which throws alert box, but its not working when I get 1.png in correct position.  Any ideas?  My conditional statement seems to make sense, just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Thanks again!

Comment: Figured it out.  I was not providing the full path name that images[i].src was returning : )